# Why was my bounty returned?

Tags: support, bounty

I have posted [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1234488/260636) about a month ago. As nobody said anything, I offered a 50 points bounty yesterday. So I got two answers, none correct.

To my surprise, someone returned my points, cancelling the bounty, and probably the same person also downvoted the question without further explanation (this strengthens my point of view that at least the first downvote should be forced to leave a comment, the remaining downvotes should be forced to at least vote in an existing comment).

Why was the bounty returned?

Comment: Being the moderator who removed the bounty (because it is off topic and prepared for close/migration), no, it was not also downvoted

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your bounty was refunded because the question itself is off topic for the site, so no point in awarding a bounty for it when it should instead be closed or migrated.

And you cannot do either with an active bounty.

Some may just answer anyway hoping that the bounty will be awarded to them by way of expiration or default. Others will choose to flag a moderator to let us know.

Both cases happened here. But it still is not on topic for the site and so as mentioned, needed to refund the bounty to close/migrate the question.

Answer (score -7):

[Bounties](https://superuser.com/help/bounty) expire after a short period, it was returned to you because none of the answers given were upvoted or accepted.

As an aside, your question is also off-topic for SuperUser as it refers to the web application Youtube. The tag [youtube](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/youtube) says:

> Go to Web Apps Stack Exchange unless you require heavy integration with a desktop installation.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't seen that. But I offered the bounty yesterday. The short period you mention is usually longer.

Comment: "*it was returned to you because none of the answers given were upvoted or accepted*" that's not how bounty works. [A moderator refunded it because the question is off-topic and needs to be closed/migrated](https://meta.superuser.com/a/12626/356789). Otherwise, it can't be closed while there's an active bounty.

Comment: @burgi. That is not how bounties work. Normally you don't get bounties back. If no answers are awarded the bounty you lose it. An exception is if a mod returns the bounty so that some other action may be taken (such as closing the question as off-topic).

Comment: Everyday is a school day! I learnt something new here.